# Как проверить, существует ли определённая строка внутри другой строки с определённым условием

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, char

Мне нужно написать функцию, которая возвращает `true` в случае если из первой строки, можно собрать вторую. И `false` если нельзя. Например:

```
scramble('rkqodlw', 'world') ==> True
scramble('cedewaraaossoqqyt', 'codewars') ==> True
scramble('katas', 'steak') ==> False
scramble('scriptjavx', 'javascript') ==> False
```

Вот, что я уже попробовал:

```
https://pastebin.com/Hw2qdGuB
```

Но код не проходит тест, когда в строке содержится одинаковое количество каких-либо символов, например в случае №4 символ `a`. Как можно реализовать алгоритм иначе и более эффективно?

Comment: просто посчитай количество появлений каждого отдельного символа в каждой строке и сравни...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Каждого отдельного символа? Сколько строчек на это уйдёт?
Я думаю, что возможно вы немного не поняли вопрос.

Comment: каких «строчек»?

Comment: Имею ввиду строчек кода

Comment: нум... строк в 30 решение уместится должно...

Comment: имеется ввиду, что у нас есть массив s[a1, a2 ... an], и строка p[x1,x2....xz] и нам надо понять существует ли такая перестановка подмножества s = p?

Comment: Имеется ввиду, можно ли собрать из символов первой строки вторую строку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool scramble(string s1, string s2) {
    unordered_multiset<char> letters(s1.begin(), s1.end());
    for(char& c : s2) {
        const auto it = letters.find(c);
        if (it != letters.end()) {
            letters.erase(it);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: хэш таблицы плохая вещь, на довольно больших строках будет работать очень долго, лучше просто хранить массив пар

Comment: @Neuro, там же символы, а не строки

Comment: Ну на строке из 1000000 "a" хэш-таблица с повторным хэшированием будет постоянно перевычислять хэш. Так как та работает за n/m , или за нерабочую O(1). Но это просто анти тесты, без них довольно хорошая структура данных

Comment: @Neuro, так будет 1000000 символов 'a', а не строк "a". Какой там хэш вычисляться-то будет? Это и так число в диапазоне от 0 до 255.

Comment: да если понимать как работает unordered_set, если хэш от символа строки и тд совпадает, он не как в list ht вставляется в конец листа, а перевычисляет хэш с новым модификатором и вставляет, так как 10^7 'a' создадут неимоверную коллизию и все будет работать очень медленно

Comment: @Neuro, на 1000000 `"a"` с `multiset`'ом всё должно быть нормально — он не проверяет присутствует ли элемент при вставке, а при поиске, если присутствует, то возвращает первый попавшийся... а вот если случится всего одна коллизия, с другим элементом, то при `find()` начнётся ад и израиль...

Comment: @КириллМалышев прочитайте как работает открытое хэширование, там при вставке элементов у которых изначально один хэш в хэш добавляется модификатор, который увеличивается при коллизиях, и поэтому при вставке кучи одинаковых букв будет столько же коллизий, он будет хранить все эти буквы в разных ячейках, но при этом поддерживать все эти коллизии

Comment: Тогда уж проще `set_difference`? И не проще ли массив (как в моем ответе)?

Comment: @Neuro "строки из 1000000" не стоит вообще передавать по значению :)

Comment: Ну, это уж точно из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно"...

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так.

```
bool scramble(const string& a, const string& b) {
    int s[256] = {0};
    for(char c: a) s[(unsigned char)c]++;
    for(char c: b) if (--s[(unsigned char)c] < 0) return false;
    return true;
    }
```